# query object where function filter

Tags: mobile, service, azure

I am trying to implement my business logic in the Azure layer and I just do not grasp this node.js style of scripts on Insert.

I have T-SQL that works for this

```
declare @latitude decimal(23,20)
declare @longitude decimal(23,20)
declare @timeStamp datetime

set @latitude = 37.7858340000000012537
set @longitude = -122.4064170000000046911
set @timeStamp = '2012-12-25 02:58:23'

select longitude, latitude, userid
from blah.actions ba
where 
(
    datediff(second, ba.TimeStamp, @timeStamp) < 5 and
    (ba.longitude - 0.0001 <= @longitude and ba.longitude + 0.0001 >= @longitude) and
    (ba.latitude - 0.0001 <= latitude and ba.latitude + 0.0001 >= latitude) 
)
```

The question is, how do I use a function to filter the table query within an Azure script on Insert?

So a little more work. I figured out how to filter with a function (but I am still struggling with how to debug the Azure scripts). I have the following on my Insert. I have it "working",in the fact that I no longer receive "Internal Server Error", but I have no idea how to log the results or view them (any tips on this Azure stuff are greatly appreciated). I am starting to realize just how much more work I have to do on this application.

```
function dateDiff(date1, date2) 
{
    return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime() / 1000;
}

function insert(item, user, request) {

    request.execute();

    var actionsTable = tables.getTable('BlahActions');

    actionsTable.where(function(currentLat, currentLon, currentTime)
    {
        return (this.Latitude - 0.0001 <= currentLat && this.Latitude + 0.0001 >= currentLat) &&
               (this.Longitude - 0.0001 <= currentLon && this.Longitude + 0.0001 >= currentLon) &&
               (this.TimeStamp == currentTime);
               //(dateDiff(this.TimeStamp, currentTime) <= 5);
    }, item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.TimeStamp)
    .read(
    {
        success:function(results)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

The problem with the above script is Azure pukes when using the getTime(). I need to grab all of the entries that are close to the same latitude and longitude and that have occurred within the past X seconds (yes, essentially reinventing the "bump"). This is where I am currently stuck. I will update when/if I make it passed this part.

Answer (score 0):

A few lessons learned here.
First and foremost, the Log files are viewable with the menu at the top of the root of the mobile service where it says "LOGS"...#epicFacePalm.
Second, now that I can see the actual error message and not something generic from within my XCode IDE

- The return statement inside the predicate for the where method must do simple comparisons only -- you cannot make a call to another method and check the return value in your conditional statements -- that puked on me.
- The other technical detail was to change my TimeStamp column from DateTime to double -- completely simplifies the subtraction of the time stamps with no conversions necessary -- simple

With that said, I now have this in the where method

```
    actionsTable.where(function(currentLat, currentLon, currentTime)
    {
        return (this.Latitude - 0.0001 <= currentLat && this.Latitude + 0.0001 >= currentLat) &&
            (this.Longitude - 0.0001 <= currentLon && this.Longitude + 0.0001 >= currentLon) &&
           (currentTime - this.TimeStamp <= 5);
    }, item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.TimeStamp)
```

to filter the results before I filter them in the success callback

```
.read(
{
    success:function(results)
    {            
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
       {
            var obj = results[i];

            for(var key in obj)
            {
                if (key === "id" && 
                    distance(obj.Longitude, obj.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Latitude) < 30)
                {                        
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

The whole thing for syntax clarity

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
request.execute();

var actionsTable = tables.getTable('blahActions');
console.log("Inserting new action '%j'", item);

actionsTable.where(function(currentLat, currentLon, currentTime)
{
    return (this.Latitude - 0.0001 <= currentLat && this.Latitude + 0.0001 >= currentLat) &&
           (this.Longitude - 0.0001 <= currentLon && this.Longitude + 0.0001 >= currentLon) &&
           (currentTime - this.TimeStamp <= 5);
}, item.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.TimeStamp)
.read(
{
    success:function(results)
    {            
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
       {
            var obj = results[i];

            for(var key in obj)
            {
                if (key === "id" && 
                    distance(obj.Longitude, obj.Latitude, item.Longitude, item.Latitude) < 30)
                {                        
                }
            }
       }
    }
});
```

}